# *ngFor starts creating html element from bottom

Tags: angular, ngfor

I want to create something like a trello board. For that I wrote 2 columns with style as width = 20% and display = inline block. In one column I have used *ngFor for printing dynamic elements and in other column i have written `<mat-list-item></mat-list-item>` for multiple cards. Please find the code and screenshot below.
[image: 1]

And Please find the code from app.component.ts as below.
[image: 2]

My problem is I am not understanding why *ngFor code skips few spaces initially and then starts printing the inner code at the bottom to match up the static data from the second column. Please refer to screenshot 1 for better understanding. Thank you in advance.(I have used latest version of angular and angular material)

Comment: Even if I use static data in both the columns, the list doesnt start from the top.

Comment: provide a stackblitz?

Comment: You can add `vertical-align: top` to  your left column.  `<div class="container" style="width: 20%; display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;">`.  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fdkfkz

Comment: @JasonWhite Worked.! But why do I have to add it explicitly? Why doesnt it start from the top. BTW Thank you  so much for your help .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with the `inline-block` of the `container` items.  The default `vertical-align` value for `inline-block` is `baseline`.  If you set both columns to `vertical-align: top` they will both start from the top.

> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fdkfkz
>
> http://infoheap.com/css-inline-block-baseline-alignment/

---

**Note**: If you're using bootstrap, you should probably structure it how @Rick suggested instead of doing the inline styles.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may want to use this format:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      //first list here
    </div>    
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      //second list list here
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Rick, will follow this structure